# Fetch data from database and use it to make markers in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mysql-connect

I am new to Javascript. I want to fetch lat-long from MySQL (more then 100) and use it to add markers on Google Maps.

To do this I think i've to use php -server side programming. I am able to pass array from PHP to Javascript. Here it is

```
   <?
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'pwd') or die(mysql_error()); 
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";

mysql_select_db("pro_user") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info"); 
$no=count($result);
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{
    $a[$i]=$row['city'];
    $b[$i]=$row['loc_lat'];
    $c[$i]=$row['loc_long'];
    $i++;
}
  ?>
  <html> 
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function initialize() 
{ 
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(22.3038945, 70.8021599); 
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8, 
        center: latlng, 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    }; 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 

<?  for($i=0;$i<count($a); $i++)
    {
        echo "a[$i]='".$a[$i]."';\n";
        echo "b[$i]='".$b[$i]."';\n";
        echo "c[$i]='".$c[$i]."';\n";       

    } 
?>
    function createMarker(latitude,longitude,title) 
    { 
        var markerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: markerLatLng, map: map, title: title }); 
    }
    createMarker(22.3038945, 70.8021599,'Gujarat');

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {   
        document.write(a[i]);
        document.write(b[i]);
        document.write(c[i]);

        initialize().createMarker(b[i], c[i], a[i]);
    }       

} 

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="getData()"></body>
    </html>
```

Now I am stuck. I am not able to pass Javascript array to make markers.

Comment: I would remove your actual MySQL username and password from your question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple tutorial on the google maps website for doing this using PHP / XML / MySQL and Javascript ....

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply. is there any other way to do same thing just by using PHP and Javascript? please let me know.

Comment: @anand you mean not use XML ? sure just use an array instead of XML and loop the array

Comment: here what I am trying but it is not working. I am able to print it using js but not able to fetch on map

Comment: Updated (original) the code, please have look and let me know where I am making mistake.

Comment: your calling ` initialize().createMarker(b[i], c[i], a[i]);` this doesnt work with you Javascript setup - just called `initialise()` then  `createMarker(b[i], c[i], a[i]);`

Comment: That is also not working. I tried this thing:

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  { 
   document.write(a[i]);
   document.write(b[i]);
   document.write(c[i]);
   var lat = new GLatLng(parseFloat(b[i]));
   var lon = new GLatLng(parseFloat(c[i]));
   var tit = new GLatLng(parseFloat(a[i]));
   map.addOverlay(new creatMarker(lat, lon, tit));
}
 but this is also not creating Markers on Map.